# How to call main() again after running my program without restarting program

Tags: python

Question: I would like my program to restart after it runs. Meaning I want it to ask the user to enter the hour again. How do I do that? We haven't covered it in class and I was unsuccessful in my attempts to Google it. I feel like if I took out main() it would run ad infinite but I have to have def main() in there...

Here is my code:

```
def main():
    #Input
    hour = int(input("Enter the hour: ")) 
    if hour >= 1 and hour <= 12 : # Insures that the user inputs a number between "1" and "12"
       suffix = input("Enter the suffix: ")
       suffix = suffix.lower()
       if suffix == "pm" and hour == 12: # Handles user input of "12pm" 
          hour = 12
          print(hour)   
       elif suffix == "pm" and hour <= 12: # Handles all other "pm" user inputs
          hour = hour + 12
          print(hour) 
       elif suffix == "am" and hour == 12: # Handles user input of "12am"
          print("0")
       elif suffix == "am": # Handles all other "am" user inputs
          print(hour)
       else : 
          print("Error: The suffix must be am or pm.")
    else :
       print("Error: The hour must be between 1 and 12.")

main()
```

Comment: In the else part after the print statement add main(). If user enters wrong input, the program will again ask for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this help?

```
while True:
    main()
```

Comment: Yes. As soon as the cool down passes I'll add this as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def main():
    #Input
    hour = int(input("Enter the hour: ")) 
    if hour >= 1 and hour <= 12 : # Insures that the user inputs a number between "1" and "12"
       suffix = input("Enter the suffix: ")
       suffix = suffix.lower()
       if suffix == "pm" and hour == 12: # Handles user input of "12pm" 
          hour = 12
          print(hour)   
       elif suffix == "pm" and hour <= 12: # Handles all other "pm" user inputs
          hour = hour + 12
          print(hour) 
       elif suffix == "am" and hour == 12: # Handles user input of "12am"
          print("0")
       elif suffix == "am": # Handles all other "am" user inputs
          print(hour)
       else : 
          print("Error: The suffix must be am or pm.")
    else :
       print("Error: The hour must be between 1 and 12.")

while True:
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use while loop for asking hour from user every time and keep your program running:

```
def main():
    while(True):
        #Input
        hour = int(input("Enter the hour: ")) 
        if hour >= 1 and hour <= 12 : # Insures that the user inputs a number between "1" and "12"
            suffix = input("Enter the suffix: ")
            suffix = suffix.lower()
            if suffix == "pm" and hour == 12: # Handles user input of "12pm" 
                hour = 12
                print(hour)   
            elif suffix == "pm" and hour <= 12: # Handles all other "pm" user inputs
                hour = hour + 12
                print(hour) 
            elif suffix == "am" and hour == 12: # Handles user input of "12am"
                print("0")
            elif suffix == "am": # Handles all other "am" user inputs
                print(hour)
            else : 
                print("Error: The suffix must be am or pm.")
        else :
            print("Error: The hour must be between 1 and 12.")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a loop with an exit condition like so:

```py
def main():
    #Input
    hour = int(input("Enter the hour: ")) 
    if hour >= 1 and hour <= 12 : # Insures that the user inputs a number between "1" and "12"
       suffix = input("Enter the suffix: ")
       suffix = suffix.lower()
       if suffix == "pm" and hour == 12: # Handles user input of "12pm" 
          hour = 12
          print(hour)   
       elif suffix == "pm" and hour <= 12: # Handles all other "pm" user inputs
          hour = hour + 12
          print(hour) 
       elif suffix == "am" and hour == 12: # Handles user input of "12am"
          print("0")
       elif suffix == "am": # Handles all other "am" user inputs
          print(hour)
       else : 
          print("Error: The suffix must be am or pm.")
    else :
       print("Error: The hour must be between 1 and 12.")


def end():
    inpt = input("Do you want to continue? (y/n)")
    if(inpt == 'y'):
        return True
    else:
        return False

run = True

while run:
    main()
    run = end()
```

This way the user will be asked if he would like to continue every run.

Another option would be, to call `main()` Multiple times.

As to your question about removing the `main()` call, your program wouldn't do anything in that case.